# Android How to implement location globally search using FourSquare APi?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, foursquare

I want to implement location search of world in android. I am using foursquare api. Always i am getting near by venues only. 
I am using below code

```
VenuesCriteria v = new VenuesCriteria();
v.setLocation(getLocationObj());
v.setRadius(1000);
v.setQuery(newText);
v.setQuantity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

v.setIntent(VenuesCriteriaIntent.BROWSE);
async.getVenuesNearby(this, v);
```

Can you please me thanks.

Comment: set higher radius  `v.setRadius(6371000);` `6371000` Earth Radius in meters

Comment: Its not working at all....